# UnfoldingMaps tutorial wrong

Tags: java, maps

To get the below code to run, I need to either:
comment out MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);

or

change map type to UnfoldingMap[] map;

it seems to me that the [tutorial](http://unfoldingmaps.org/tutorials/getting-started-in-eclipse.html) is wrong in this regard. the error I see in eclipse is:

```
The method createDefaultEventDispatcher(PApplet, UnfoldingMap[]) in the type MapUtils is not applicable for the arguments (SampleMapApp, UnfoldingMap)
```

Can anyone suggest to me how I can fix this?

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.UnfoldingMap;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.AbstractMapProvider;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.Google;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.geo.Location;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.MapUtils;

public class SampleMapApp extends PApplet {

    UnfoldingMap map;

    public void setup() {
        AbstractMapProvider provider = new Google.GoogleTerrainProvider();
        size(800, 600, P2D);
        map = new UnfoldingMap(this, 50, 50, 500, 350, provider);

        // Show map around the location in the given zoom level.
        map.zoomAndPanTo(14, new Location(53.385f, -6.161f));
        // Add mouse and keyboard interactions
        MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);
    }

    public void draw() {
        map.draw();
    }

}
```

Comment: Does `createDefaultEventDispatcher` take an array or varargs (i.e. `UnfoldingMap...`)?

Comment: `method ...UnfoldingMap[]) not applicable for .. UnfoldingMap)` Those `[]` mean that it's expecting an array of unfolding maps. Though it's varargs http://unfoldingmaps.org/javadoc/de/fhpotsdam/unfolding/utils/MapUtils.html .. weird. That should not error.. Old version (back from 1.5 java times) of eclipse / java maybe?

Comment: Troubleshooting further, on a freshly installed machine I installed the latest eclipse and java-8 (official). I then followed the tutorial here and it still doesn't work: http://unfoldingmaps.org/tutorials/getting-started-in-eclipse.html

Comment: Unfolding developer here. Yes, that is weird. It also is independent of the version of Unfolding, as we never had a method signature with an array (only ever a list or a varargs).

So, maybe this is something else and it just gives this error message? Can you try moving the provider initiation a bit further down? Processing asks you to have the size-call as first statement in the setup. (Also, which Processing version are you using?)

Comment: in order to reduce the variables, I have elected to use the baked-in example 'SimpleMapApp.java'  and am running processing-3.0.1

Answer (score 2):

OK, turns out that downloading the latest and greatest processing has fixed the issue. I'd love to know why the code 'mostly' works though if it was a library issue all along. thanks tnagel for getting me to check the processing version.

Comment: `sudo apt install libprocessing-core-java` for ubuntu